# Getting ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'plotnine' when import on Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, plotnine

I'm following a plotnine tutorial to do some plotting on Jupyter Notebook. But when I imported

`from plotnine import *`

I got an error: `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'plotnine'`.

I'm new on Jupyter and plotnine. Have tried different things searched, but still don't know how to solve this ...

Comment: did you do `pip install plotnine`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure `plotnine` is installed in your environment. Without more information about your environment, I can't give you a definitive answer, but this might work

1. make a new empty cell in jupyter
2. write `!pip install plotnine` into cell
3. execute cell

This should install `plotnine` and you can use it from now one (and you can delete the cell, plotnine is now a permanent part of your environment)

Comment: If running Jupyter out of a virtual environment, you shouldn't use ``--user`` as per user site packages is ignored when using a virtual environment.

Comment: Thanks. `!conda install -c conda-forge --yes plotnine` also worked.

Answer (score 1):

In my case everything has failed, everytime it showed **no module named plotnine** however, requirement was already satisfied.

My problem got resolved by this command on terminal
`conda install -c conda-forge plotnine`

source link : https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/plotnine

Comment: That's already commented by @Tyler on the accepted answer post